# SQL Declaring a variable as a select result, does it run select every time it's called?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a simple declare :

```
[...]
DECLARE
   _cod_instance bigint := (SELECT max(cod_instance)
                            FROM   public.instance
                            WHERE  cod_process = _cod_process);

BEGIN
[...]
```

Does the select get executed every time I call the variable _cod_instance? or with the declaration of it the result of the select is being saved temporary for the use of this function call? I know I could probably test it myself using explain analyze, but I'm kind of new on sql and i still haven't come close to understand everything there.

Comment: No.  The value is calculated and assigned to the variable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks!